# Script to Scan Branches and Release

Tags: scripting, cron, git-branch

My goal is to ssh into several host, check when the current branch was modified, and if older than 48 hours, mark the host as available. Eventually, I'll need to schedule this as a cron job but I haven't gotten to that level yet.

I have this:

```
hosts="rick morty beth jerry summer"
extra_vars="release_branch=$1"

show_deployed_branches() {
    for host in $hosts
    do
        if [[ ! -z "$branch_dir" ]]; then
            branchstamp=`$SHELL_AS ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $host cat $branch_dir/* 2> /dev/null`
            printf " [*] %s:\n%s\n" $host "$branchstamp"
        else
            branchstamp=`$SHELL_AS ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $host cat $branch_file 2> /dev/null`
            printf " [*] %s: %s\n" $host "$branchstamp"
        fi
    done
}
```

This will show the following:

```
 [*] rick: GLIB-1111 on February 28 at 08:30 UTC by Birdman
 [*] morty: BLEM-2371 on February 26 at 16:55 UTC by Birdman
 [*] beth: AVAILABLE
 [*] jerry: DOPE-12 on March 01 at 19:28 UTC by Birdman
 [*] summer: MAIN on March 01 at 18:17 UTC by MrPoopyButthole
```

If I want to make Jerry available, I run the following:

```
release_box(jerry) {
    $SHELL_AS ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $1 "echo 'AVAILABLE' > $branch_file" 2> /dev/null
    echo " [*] Finished with $1"
```

I know this requires an if statement, but I'm stumped on next steps. I know an If statement is needed but don't know what will read the modified date and determine that its too old.

Comment: Will the ctime or mtime of the file containing the branchstamp match the date in it? If so you can base the `if` on result of `find -mtime` or `find -ctime`. If that is not guaranteed, then you may have to parse the branchstamp and turn it into something you can more easily compare against (cf. `date +%s`)

Comment: Great question! That actually helped me realize that I was looking at the wrong time. When Birdman connects to Rick Host, he deploys a branch GLIB-1111. The time is actually the deploy time. Additionally, the job should be automatically released after 48 hours.